# Ajax call remove the special characters from post

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following AJAX call

```
url: '/Admin/UserManagmentUpdatemobile',
                type: 'GET',
                data: "UserName=" + userName + "&Email=" + corpEmail + "&MobileNo=" + mobileNo
```

and the mobile number has this `value ='+97111111111'` when the data posted to the server it removes the + how can i handle this ,
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass the data as an object to jQuery.ajax it will be encoded properly

```
url: '/Admin/UserManagmentUpdatemobile',
type: 'GET',
data: {UserName: userName, Email: corpEmail, MobileNo: mobileNo},
```

you can manually encode it if you want with `encodeURIComponent`

```
data: "UserName=" + encodeURIComponent(userName) + "&Email=" + encodeURIComponent(corpEmail) + "&MobileNo=" + encodeURIComponent(mobileNo)
```